# "Import Error: widgets" In Qtile ArchLinux

Tags: python, linux

When I use this code

```
widget.Battery(
format = 'Battery: {percent:2.0%}',
foreground = colors[2],
background = colors[5],
padding = 5
),
```

it Work completly Fine but when I use this code

```
widget.CPU(
foreground = colors[2],
background = colors[4],
threshold = 90,
padding = 5
),
```

at bar it shows `Import Error: CPU` and it happnes with memory net and all those widgets

these thing i have imported

```
import os
import re
import socket
import subprocess
from libqtile import *
from libqtile.config import Click, Drag, Group, KeyChord, Key, Match, Screen
from libqtile.command import lazy
from libqtile.lazy import lazy
from libqtile.utils import guess_terminal
from typing import List
from libqtile.widget import *
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, have you searched for the error message online? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install all the requirements of each widget.

For example, for the CPU widget you may need the python library called [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)

You have all the information of each widget in http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/ref/widgets.html#

Comment: Yes I solved it, Sorry i forgot to update it in my account

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
from libqtile.widget import *
```

to

```
from libqtile import widget
```